# Get the handle of a window with not fully known title. (C#)

Tags: c#, api

The title is partially static with an variable suffix. For example *"Window Title {- user_id}"*.

How can I get the handle without knowing the exact title?

Comment: Appendix? I think you mean suffix. I'll fix it for you.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look through all the Processes and check the [MainWindowTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx).  (You can use regexps, or `StartsWith`, etc)

```
foreach(Process proc in Process.GetProcesses())
{
   if(proc.MainWindowTitle.StartsWith("Some String"))
   {
      IntPtr handle = proc.MainWindowHandle;
      // ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. Should work in most cases. But what happens if a process has more than one top lavel window?

Comment: Thanks! Wow, I never knew you could get around this and avoid Win32 API kludges.

Answer (score 5):

[This CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/runninginstanceie.aspx) describes how to enumerate Top level windows (Based on Win32 API [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497.aspx)).
You can easily modify it to filter on a partial window title: Modify EnumWindowsCallBack.

HTH.

Answer (score 2):

Get by class name and parent window handle. For example: get start button handle using win32api. First you know parent window class name using spyxx tool.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr handleParent, IntPtr handleChild, string className, string WindowName);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string className, string windowTitle);
```

Usage:

```
IntPtr handle = FindWindowEx(FindWindow("Shell_TrayWnd",null), new IntPtr(0), "Button", null);
```