# Retrieving the parent window Handle C# (trying to maximize outlook)

Tags: c#

I generally do run the method listed below to maximize iconized windows; 
however when it comes to outlook, there are times where it will maximize a Mail (message) that i have open instead of the parent application (outlook) ; its just pulling up anything outlook that it finds and i need the parent, how can i achieve this?

I have tried using WINAPI GetAncestor, I have also tried  GetParent  .

```
    public static bool EventChecking(string progr)
    {
        int bb = 0;
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(progr).Length > 0)
        {
            bb++;
        }

        if (bb == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        foreach (Process ddcd in Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (ddcd.ProcessName.Contains(progr))
            {
                if (ddcd.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
                {
                    pointer = ddcd.MainWindowHandle;
                    if (IsIconic(pointer))
                    {
                        SendMessage(pointer, 0x112, 0xF120, 0);
                    }

                    SetForegroundWindow(pointer);
                }
            };

        }
        return true;
    }
```

EDIT:

I also recently tried:

```
if (ddcd.MainWindowTitle.EndsWith("- Outlook"))
```

and it still pulls up the single email

Comment: Perhaps this may help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/637652/get-the-handle-of-a-window-with-not-fully-known-title-c

Comment: Its still pulling up the single email; i searched now for endswith "- outlook"   only the main window ends with this string not the single emails;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also had trouble working with Outlook via C# but I have had some success with Win32 calls.  Below is one way to locate the Outlook Main Window by checking the Caption.

You could also try [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497(v=vs.85).aspx) but it takes more effort to implement due to Callbacks.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public IntPtr GetOutlookHandle()
{
    string windowClass = "rctrl_renwnd32";
    uint GW_HWNDNEXT = 2;
    IntPtr firstHandle = new IntPtr(0);
    IntPtr handle = new IntPtr(0);

    // Look for a Window with the right Class
    firstHandle = FindWindow(windowClass, null);

    // Nothing Found
    if (firstHandle.Equals(IntPtr.Zero)) return IntPtr.Zero;

    // Remember where we started to avoid an infinite loop
    handle = firstHandle;

    do
    {
        // Check the Caption to find the Main Window
        if (GetWindowCaption(handle).EndsWith(" - Microsoft Outlook"))
        {
           return handle;
        }

        // Get the next Window with the same Class
        handle = GetWindow(handle, GW_HWNDNEXT);

    } while (handle != firstHandle);

    // Didn't find any matches
    return IntPtr.Zero;
}


private static string GetWindowCaption(IntPtr windowHandle)
{
    // Determine Length of Caption
    int length = GetWindowTextLength(windowHandle);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length + 1);

    // Get Window Caption
    GetWindowText(windowHandle, sb, sb.Capacity);
    return sb.ToString();
}

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetWindow(IntPtr hWnd, uint uCmd);

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);

[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);
```